# How to get the username or user uid in hook_user for logout operation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal 6 I want to get the username or user uid when user logged out. I tried with hook_user for logout operation in a custom module but without success. Allways I get the anonymous user.

Comment: I don't know a way of getting the user id after logged out.
I think you can do some work around of putting the user data in cookies/session and use it after logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Inside [`hook_user`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_user/6), the account being logged out is accessible  in the `$account` object passed as a function parameter:

```
hook_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL)
```

The UID can be found in `$account->uid` and the name in `$account->name`.